# Finite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

A finite sequence of numbers is called AWESOME if each subsequent member of the sequence, except the first one, is larger than the previous one and if the product of all the members of that sequence is a perfect square. For example, sequence 2,6,27 is an AWESOME sequence. Determine the natural numbers x and y such that the sequence 28,x,y,65 is an AWESOME sequence.

Is this a disordered sequence? Because I've tried so many times and I just can't see a pattern in this sequence. All I know is that x and y should be numbers between 28 and 65 and y is greater than x. Can please someone help me solve it?

Comment: Squares ... Have you looked at prime factorizations of the example sequence, the square it produces, and the factorizations of the two numbers in your given sequence?

Comment: Yes I have. It still doesn't make sense to me. The square of the given sequence is a very small number compared to the square of the 2nd unknown sequence( im assuming)

Comment: Suppose you didn't know that $6$ was the middle term of the example sequence.  What could you determine about its prime factorization just from the prime factorization of $2$ and $27$?

Comment: Since 1st sequence consists of smaller numbers, I could've easily found out about 6 by prime factorization of 2 and 27. But sequence 2 has bigger numbers and there are two numbers between 28 and 65, so I can't really seem to find them through prime factorization.

Comment: What primes *must* be present in $x$ or $y$?

Comment: I guess 7,5, and 2. Coz these are present in 28 and 65.

Comment: $2$ is not necessary.  You missed $13$.

Comment: but isnt 13 bigger? x and y must be between 28 and 65.

Comment: We're just trying to get a list of primes that have to be present in $x$ and $y$.  There will be more than just the required primes.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You look for $ x,y $ such that
$$x<y<65$$
and
$$65\times 28xy=13\times 5xy\times 7\times 2^2$$
is a perfect square.
For example, you can take
$$x=13 \text{ and } y=5\times 7=35$$

or
$$x=35 \text{ and } y=13\times 2^2=52$$

Comment: But x must be greater than 28. It's still a confusion.

Comment: @Shabahatbangash You said except the first one.

Comment: Oh yeah. that's given too. I was so focused on the given sequence since 6 is greater than 2. Totally missed that. Thanks a lot. I guess that's the only answer of x and y right? 13 and 35 are the only numbers that could satisfy the conditions. Am i right or still missing something?

Comment: @Shabahatbangash No. there is an other. look up .

Comment: Thank you so much. Are these the only two solutions of x and y?

Comment: Yes, no others.

Comment: "Except the first one" means that the first term of the sequence is exempted from "is larger than the previous one" which would make no sense. It's just a verbose way of saying that $28\lt x\lt y\lt65$. So there is just one solution.